# How to make a CURL request with retrofit?

Tags: android, curl, request, retrofit

I'm trying to make a login.

The request looks like this $ curl -u "username:PASSWORD" https://urlhere.com

How can i make this to work using retrofit?

I tried an authorization header, something like                 request.addHeader("Authentication", username+":"+password);

Any help please?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication -- try using an `Authorization` header, with the encoded credentials.

Comment: *How to make a CURL request with retrofit?* is misleading ...

Answer (score 6):

Your question is not clear enough.
I guess that is basic auth, you can use something like this

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/login") void login(
        @Header("Authorization") String authorization,
        Callback<?> callback
);



// later when you call it

public static String getBase64String(String value) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return Base64.encodeToString(value.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.NO_WRAP);
}

final String auth = "Basic " + getBase64String("user:password");
apiClient.login(auth, callback);
```

i hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 3):

1. If you have needs use authorization only for separate rest request you can make it via [@Header](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). A request Header can be updated dynamically using the @Header annotation.

   ```
   @FormUrlEncoded
   @GET("/user")
   void getUser(@Header("Authorization") 
   String authorization, Callback<User> callback);
   ```

   Where

   ```
   String authorization = "Basic " + getBase64String("user:password");
   ```

   For instance, it will string: `Basic b2QGdyb3Vwb24ucnU6aWxvdmVteW1hbWE=`

   public static String getBase64String(String value) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
       return Base64.encodeToString(value.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.NO_WRAP);
   }
2. If you have needs use authorization for all rest requests you can add @Header via of [Retrofit Interceptor](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/RequestInterceptor.html):

   ```
   new RestAdapter.Builder().
       setClient(...).
       setEndpoint(...).
       setErrorHandler(...).
       setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
       @Override
       public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
              request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
              request.addHeader("Authorization", authorization);
              }
       }).
       build();
   ```

Answer (score 1):

To print the cURL command equivalent of a Retrofit request in an Interceptor, you can create a function that takes the RequestOptions object and constructs the cURL command from its properties. You can then print this cURL command to the console.

Here's an example of how you can do it in your AppInterceptor class:

```
class AppInterceptor extends Interceptor {
  final _prefs = locator.get<SharedPreferenceHelper>();
  @override
  void onRequest(RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) {
    options.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
    options.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer ${_prefs.getValues("token")}";
    print("cURL command: ${_buildCurlCommand(options)}");
    super.onRequest(options, handler);
  }

  String _buildCurlCommand(RequestOptions options) {
    final headers =
        options.headers.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, "-H '$key: $value'"));
    final headerString = headers.values.join(' ');

    final method = options.method;
    final url = options.uri.toString();

    if (options.data != null) {
      final data = options.data;
      return "curl -X $method $headerString '$url' -d '$data'";
    } else {
      return "curl -X $method $headerString '$url'";
    }
  }
}`
```