# CURL -u request with Retrofit

Tags: android, curl, retrofit

I am using Retrofit (not the new one) in Android to do some OAuth authorization.
I am past the first step where I get a code to use, now the next thing in the specifications is to do this:

```
curl -u : http://example.com/admin/oauth/token -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code='
```

I have never done curl requests, I don't know what to do, especially with Retrofit and it's interfaces.

I took a look at this

[How to make a CURL request with retrofit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28113629/how-to-make-a-curl-request-with-retrofit)

but this guy doesnt have a -d thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-d` argument to curl adds POST parameters.  In this case, `grant_type` and `code`.  We can encode each of those in retrofit with the `@Field` annotation.

```
public interface AuthApi {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/admin/oauth/token")
    void getImage(@Header("Authorization") String authorization,
                        @Field(("grant_type"))String grantType,
                        @Field("code") String code,
                        Callback<Object> callback);
}
```

Where the authorization field is using the `@Header` solution give on your linked question.

Usage would be like --

```
RestAdapter authAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint("http://example.com/").build();
AuthApi authApi = authAdapter.create(AuthApi.class);

try {
    final String auth = "Basic " + getBase64String(":");
    authApi.getImage(auth, "authorization_code", "", new Callback<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Object o, Response response) {
            // handle success
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            // handle failure
        }
    });
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

where `getBase64String` is helper method from your linked answer.  Copied below for completeness --

```
public static String getBase64String(String value) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return Base64.encodeToString(value.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.NO_WRAP);
}
```