# Retrofit 2 for OAuth (Convert cURL)

Tags: android, curl, oauth-2.0, retrofit2

So I am trying to use retrofit to get the access token from our OAuth secured backend.

Basically I need to covert the following cURL command into retrofit :

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&phone_number=123123123&password=12345" -u"Client_Id:Client_Secret" http://baseURL/o/token
```

Here is my service

```
public interface LoginService {

    @POST("/o/token")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Observable<LoginEntity> getAccessToken(@Field("grant_type") String grantType,
                                           @Field("phone_number") String phoneNumber,
                                           @Field("password") String password,
                                           @Header("Authorization") String authorization);


}
```

Here is my service generator code:

```
public void login(final MySubscribe<LoginEntity> subscriber, String pn, String psw) {

    mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(MyFeeds.APP_BASE_URL)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();  

    //encode pn
    String real_pn = getRealPN(pn);

    //encode the credential using base64 
    String credential = MyFeeds.CLIENT_ID+":"+MyFeeds.CLIENT_SECRET;
    String auth = null;
    try {
        auth = "Basic " + getBase64String(credential);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    LoginService service = mRetrofit.create(LoginService.class);
    Observable<LoginEntity> observable = service.getAccessToken("password", real_pn, psw, auth);

    mSubscription = observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .doOnSubscribe(new Action0() {
                @Override
                public void call() {
                    subscriber.onBegin();
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(subscriber);

}
```

However I keep getting http500 error.

I have read the following post but it doesn't help
[CURL -u request with Retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33580568/curl-u-request-with-retrofit)

Can anyone help? Thanks